# First steps in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

[image]I just started to write my Bachelor thesis and I have to do that in Latex.

Yesterday I downloaded the Texmaker and started to work on it, when I tried to check the Pdf I found out, that I still need to download the Miktex to  get a pdf..

Now when I press Quick Build I just get the following :

> `pdflatex-syntex=1-interaction=nonstopmode%.tex`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you actually install MikTeX (or similar, I tend to use TeXLive, also on windows).  After you did what Herbert said (whoich should already be the default in TeXMaker), exactly which error do you get?

Comment: Yeah I did, but do I need to connect it somehow?

Comment: I just get the error I posted in my question.

Comment: But that is not an error? Where exactly do you see this? Perhaps you can provide a screen dump?

Comment: I am using the german version, but I added a screenshot to my post, I get this after pressing quick built!

Comment: It sounds as if you first installed texmaker and only later installed miktex. This might mean, that texmaker does not find the path to where pdflatex is installed. Either go to the texmaker settings and give the full path to `pdflatex` there or maybe install again texmaker.

Comment: yeah thats true, where can I give the full path to pdflatex? What do you mean?

Comment: (1) Have you restarted texmaker since you installed MikTeX? (2) can you run latex in a dos prompt? Just start a dos prompt and run the `latex` command. Might be that miktex was not added to the path.

Comment: @Yuhe At `Options -> Configure Texmaker` [I'm using a fork, so it might be different] should be a list of all the commands which can be modified.

Comment: I would recommend adding the directory where the pdflatex binary is to your path (german: PATH umgebungsvariable) in windows. If you want to go the other route: optionen-> texmaker konfigurieren -> befehle.  You need to replace "pdflatex" and things like that by "C:/PATHTOPDFLATEX/pdflatex"

Comment: @Bort if installed correctly, this should not be needed.

Comment: @daleif if installed correctly, compiling should work.. sorry had to.. that's definitely correct, but given the details provided by OP i find this the most probable explaination

Answer (score 1):

Should be written with spaces before `-` and before `%.tex`:

> `pdflatex -syntex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Goto TeXmakers config and insert the spaces in the commands tab

Comment: Its like that.. It is just telling me, that it is not possible to quick bulid..